# location of the res.users model definition

Tags: xml-rpc, odoo

When i retrieve a record from openERP with xml-rpc of the res.users model, for company_id i get following value

```
 company_id : System.Object[]
```

I assume this is because of a many2one relationship.

But where can i find the field definition in the openERP addon directories?
and why do i only see these 2 values in the object and not more?

when i "watch" the data in visual studio i only see 2 values ( id and description )
why don't i see any other data related to the company is visual studio?

this is the visual studio C# code

```
            //read 
            ArrayList selectFields = new ArrayList();
            selectFields.Add("login");
            selectFields.Add("openid_email");
            selectFields.Add("active");
            selectFields.Add("company_id");
            Object[] resRead = openERPproxy.read(dbname, userID, pwd, "res.users", "read", resSearch.ToArray(), selectFields.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("Record details:");
            foreach (Object db in resRead)
            {
                XmlRpcStruct obj = (XmlRpcStruct)db;
                foreach (DictionaryEntry d in obj)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(d.Key + " : " + d.Value);
                }
            }
```

giving this output:

```
Record details:
groups_id : System.Int32[]
openid_email : xxx@xxx.xx
alias_id : 3031
company_id : System.Object[]
active : True
login : xxx
partner_id : 63
id : 23
```

when i inspect  the d.value when d.key = "company_id"
i get {object[2]}

Answer (score 1):

To see the field definition, Go to the server directory. Inside server, Go to server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py.

Open res_users.py and see the class res_users. For fields definition, you will find it around line no. 138.

Regarding those two values, on which version of OpenERP, you are working on ? Can you post your code, if possible ?